# How did the Trade Federation plan to "process" Queen Amidala?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In Star Wars: Episode I: The Phantom Menace, Nute Gunray instructs a Droid Commander to "process them" (referring to Queen Amidala and her entourage). The Droid Commander then asks they be taken to "Camp Four".

From the [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html):

> QUEEN AMIDALA, SIO BIBBLE, and FIVE OF HER HANDMAIDENS (EIRTAE, YANE, PADME, RABE, SACHE) are surrounded by TWENTY DROIDS. CAPTAIN PANAKA and FOUR NABOO GUARDS are also held at gunpoint. NUTE and RUNE stand in the middle of the room.
>
> **BIBBLE** : ...how will you explain this invasion to the Senate?
>
> **NUTE** : The Naboo and the Federation will forge a treaty that will
>   legitimize our occupation here. I've been assured it will be ratified by
>   the Senate.
>
> **AMIDALA** : I will not co-operate.
>
> **NUTE** : Now, now, your Highness. You are not going to like what we have in
>   store for your people. In time, their suffering will persuade you to see
>   our point of view. Commander. (OOM-9 steps forward) ***Process them.***
>
> **OOM-9** : Yes, sir! (turns to his sergeant) ***Take them to Camp Four.***
>
> The SERGEANT marches the GROUP out of the throne room.

Later, it is mentioned her life may be in danger, but then the danger is brushed aside:

> **AMIDALA** : Thank you, Ambassador, but my place is here with my people.
>
> **QUI-GON** : They will kill you if you stay.
>
> **BIBBLE** : They wouldn't dare.
>
> **CAPT. PANAKA** : They need her to sign a treaty to make this invasion of
>   theirs legal. ***They can't afford to kill her.***

Was the Trade Federation prepared to harm Queen Amidala herself (rather than her people) to get her to sign the treaty?

What could "process them" refer to?

Comment: Paperwork. Bureaucrats love paperwork.

Answer (score 6):

> Was the Trade Federation prepared to harm Queen Amidala herself (rather than her people) to get her to sign the treaty?

As Amidala herself proved, a body double would more than suffice. You didn't have to have the real Amidala, per se. Not having a compliant Amidala, however, would also bring certain [problems](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124349/if-queen-amidala-had-signed-the-treaty-would-the-republic-senate-recognize-it-a), but nothing that having a Sith Lord in the driver's seat of the government couldn't overcome ("I will *make* it legal"). Still, we're early in that game.

> What could "process them" refer to?

You have to process a prisoner before putting them into a prison, which is what Camp Four apparently was. This means you search them for contraband materials (like weapons) and typically issue uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

Amidala would not have been harmed. They wanted her to sign the treaty, the only time she would be “harmed” is when they were probably going to terminate her afterwards. I think “process” means maybe they were going to search her or any of the others for weapons etc. but yes if the Jedi did not rescue the Queen then she would have been taken to Camp 4 searched imprisoned with Padme and the others. Probably Padme would give in and sign the treaty due to her people suffering and starving right next to her eyes.

After she signed the treaty they would have probably got Darth Maul to decapitate her on live broadcast to the Republic and Palpatine would be able to vote no confidence in Valorum and become chancellor. But yes, even if the Queen did or didn’t sign the treaty Palpatine wins either way so yes. No harm to the Queen process= searched.

Comment: There’s a lot of speculation here with no evidence or much reasoning to back it up. Could you [edit] this to add some evidence in at least?